# .eml files not getting uploaded while sending it from email to databse

Tags: upload, file-type, restriction, eml

While sending the eml file attachment from mail to the application. It should show the attachment in supporting documents on application but eml files are not shown and also same can’t see eml file in database , so how is it working from email to application DB ? is it bcoz of dot net restrictions? Anyone can give a hint ?

I tried sending the email having eml and msg attachment in it and then saw in application that eml file is not there but msg is there , so while opening that i looked in network tab and went to that service in backend but saw that the  supporting document is coming from DB and there is no eml file but msg file type its showing…so little confused that where can be restrictions to file type in backend or the path from email to application i.e dot net is it because of restrictions in dot net?.